# My variable is crossed out in Visual Code

Tags: javascript, deprecated

My editor (VS Code) shows that my variable is deprecated. The "event" variable is struck out, but in my prof's video, it isn't so I'm assuming something is wrong. Please help!

```
document.querySelector("#myCanvas").onclick = function(){
    console.log("click", event);
}
```

[image]

I called the variable in the function which fixed it, but now I'm trying to do "onkeydown" and nothing is happening when I refresh the HTML

```
document.querySelector("#myCanvas").onmousemove = function(event){

    // console.log(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
    // console.log("click", event);
}


document.onkeydown = function(){
    console.log("keypress" ,event);
}
```

Comment: Likely you are using a deprecated variable

Comment: You might have different typings or extensions that highlight that

Comment: What does the ide tell you when you hover over the crossed out section?

Comment: @cloned it tells me: var event: Event
deprecated

'event' is deprecated.ts(6385)
lib.dom.d.ts(17162, 5): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.

Answer (score 1):

The "global" event property (i.e., `window.event`) is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event). Why is it global here? Because you didn't pass the `event` returned by the `onclick` callback to your `onclick` event handler, like this:

```js
document.querySelector("#myCanvas").onclick = function(event) {
    console.log("click", event);
}
```

Comment: i did that and it worked (Thank you), now i tried doing (onkeydown) and nothing is happening when i refresh the HTML '
document.querySelector("#myCanvas").onmousemove = function(event){

    // console.log(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
    // console.log("click", event);
}


document.onkeydown = function(){
    console.log("keypress" ,event);
}'